# Converter de string para list?

Tags: python, string, data, lista

Precisava de passar uma `string` do tipo:

```
0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1
```

para uma `list`

```
[0.4350, 0.8798, 0.0099, 1]
```

com um `script` simples. Como o posso fazer?

Comment: Dê o resultado esperado Hugo?

Answer (score 8):

Se você tem uma string com "0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1", precisa fazer duas operações: separar os elementos onde houver espaço em branco, e, para cada elemento separado, que será uma string, transforma-lo em um número float.

A primeira operação sempre será feita pelo método "split" de strings em Python. Por padrão esse método ainda tem a vantagem de considerar qualquer numero de espaços em branco (e outros caracteres de espaçamento como newline, tabs, etc...) como um único espaço:

```
>>> a = "0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1"
>>> b = a.split()
>>> b
['0.4350', '0.8798', '0.0099', '1']
```

Para quem está nos primeiros passos em Python, a forma fácil de entender para fazer a segunda operação é criar uma lista em branco, e um `for` que pra cada elemento em `b` adicione  o seu valor convertido para float na nova lista:

```
>>> c = []
>>> for elemento in b:
...     c.append(float(elemento))
... 
>>> c
[0.435, 0.8798, 0.0099, 1.0]
```

Mas assim que as pessoas se tornam mais confortáveis com Python, o ideal para isso é usar uma "list comprehension" - é uma expressão da sitnaxe do Pythonq ue permite criar uma lista a partir de uma sequência arbitrária usando um `for` na mesma linha - como uma expressão.  O seu problema todo seria resolvido assim:

```
c = [float(elemento) for elemento in "0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1".split()]
```

(O conteúdo de c será  o mesmo do exemplo anterior). 
O que essa forma faz: primeiro é executada a expressão que o "for" vai usar, depois do "in" - isso é sua string inicial (que pode estar numa variável, claro), com a aplicação do método `split`. Aí o `for` é executado, e para cada parte da sequência retornada pelo split, a expressão antes do `for`, o `float(elemento)` é executado, e o seu resultado passa a fazer parte da lista final atribuida a variável `c`.

Por fim, pessoas que não conhecem bem Python, mas acostuamdas com linguagens que permitem uma abordagem "funcional", podem apresentar soluções usando o "map" de Python, que é uma função built-in que recebe como parâmetros uma função e uma sequência, ela processa automaticamente todos os elementos da sequência passada na função - e cria uma nova sequência de saída. Na versão 2 do Python, a saída do map era uma lista direto - em Python 3, `map` cria um gerador, que deve ser transformado numa lista:

```
c = list(map(float, "0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1".split()))
```

A versão com list-comprehension em geral é mais expressiva e mais fácil de ser "pensada" do que a abordagem com a sintaxe funcional - mas não impede que por questão de gosto pessoal se use o `map`.

Answer (score 2):

Não sou desenvolvedor [python](/questions/tagged/python), mas, consegui resolver dessa forma:

#### Python versão 2x

***Código***:

```
str = '0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1';
val = filter(None, str.split(' '));
print val
```

***Saída***:

```
['0.4350', '0.8798', '0.0099', '1']
```

[Exemplo Online *IDEONE*](http://ideone.com/ntLDWz)

---

#### Python versão 3x

```
def noEmpty(x):
    return x != ""
str = '0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1';
print (list(filter(noEmpty, str.split(' '))));
```

[Exemplo OnLine *IDEONE*](http://ideone.com/0cgvQ7)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Python String split() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)
- [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845584/6797930)

Comment: Isso só funciona em Python 2.x - para perguntas onde a resposta não marcar a versão explicitamente, eu recomendaria usar Python 3 - e, em qualquer caso, dizer qual versão do Python foi usada.

Comment: @jsbueno obrigado pela dica, eu não sou desenvolvedor phython mas, o que eu fiz coloquei nas duas versões, espero que seja útil ... !!!

Comment: Legal -  valeu o esforço aí - espero que o contato com Python para criar esses exemplos tenha sido legal. Coloquei uma resposta bem didática para iniciantes e completa.

Answer (score 0):

Para você transformar uma string em lista basta você separar esta string por um carácter mais oportuno. No seu caso, o carácter mais oportuno é o carácter de espaço. Para isso, basta inserir o valor da string, deixando-a da forma...

```
a = '0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1'
```

...e, posteriormente exibir o resultado obtido pela aplicação do método **[split()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)** à variável "**a**", ou seja...

```
print(a.split())
```

Desta forma o código completo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
a = '0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1'
print(a.split())
```

Agora, se você também deseja transformar cada elemento da lista em  números reais - **[float()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#float)** - você pode, com ajuda do **[List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)**, transformar a lista - antes criada - em uma lista, na qual, cada elemento da mesma é um valor `float`.

Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
a = '0.4350    0.8798    0.0099         1'
print([float(i) for i in a.split()])
```

Comment: A resposta do jsbueno já não apresentava essa solução?